# Assign NSArray from a ViewController to go through a client

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, nsarray

I have a `NSArray` in my ViewController called `tweets`. To retrieve the tweets I have to use a method in my `TwitterClient.m` class. The method is shown below:

```
-(NSArray*)getTimeline {
        NSArray *timelineArray;
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);

            }];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    return responseArray;

}
```

However as you know you cant return the `responseArray` because it is inside a block. What would be a more efficient way to do this. 
I have another way but in this method I cannot assign the response array as the `NSArray` that is the parameter:

```
-(void)getTimeline:(NSArray*)tweetArray {
        [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self.twitterClient getPath:@"1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
            [responseArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSLog(@"Success: %@", obj);
                responseArray = tweetArray;

            }];  
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

}
```

Basically the final question is how do I assign the `tweets` array in my View Controller to equal the response array that comes in through the `TwitterClient` class.

Comment: No you cant because the `responseArray` is declared inside the block in the block above it. You see its a block within a block.. blockception!

Comment: You cant do that because the `responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject`, and the `responseObject` is declared in the block above `responseArray`

Comment: So, I don't fully understand what you're doing or trying to do exactly, but it sounds like you've walked yourself into an overly complicated mess and there's probably an easier way to do all of this.  I'm not going to spend any more time thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a block that is getting called after you are done getting your required information:

```
- (void)getTimelineWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSError *err, NSArray *arr)) block {
    [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self.twitterClient getPath:@"1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        (block ? block(nil, responseObject) : nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        (block ? block(error, nil) : nil);
    }];
}
```

You can call the method the following way:

```
[self getTimelineWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError *err, NSArray *arr) {

}];
```

Inside the completion block you have the data available and you can update your UI or whatever you intend to do. Depending on the implementation of getPath, you maybe have to dispatch the completion block on the main queue, because you are just allowed to update UI on the main thread.